# Arquillian - running tests not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to add an test based on `arquillian`. When I do `mvn test` I get this error:

Test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SomeEntityServiceTest extends ApiTestCase {
    @Inject
    CartStatusService service;

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
        someEntity.setActive(1);

        service.create(someEntity);
    }
}
```

ApiTestCase:

```
public class ApiTestCase {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myDataSource")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
        WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, “my-service.war")
                .addPackages(true, "com.project")
                .addPackage(ApiTestCase.class.getPackage())
                .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml", "test-ds.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        return archive;
    }
}
```

Maven Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

`mvn clean test` error:

```
Running com.project.api.CartStatusServiceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.275 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.project.api.CartStatusServiceTest
com.project.api.CartStatusServiceTest  Time elapsed: 1.274 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:44)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:76)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  JUnit4Provider.invoke:124->executeTestSet:153->execute:264 ? Runtime Could not...
```

Comment: please share your code and maven dependencies.

Comment: Did that. I also have an `arquillian.xml` and 2 more persistence files which I know they are correct...

Comment: yeah thats great . Now try to replace junit version from 4.11 to 4.8.1

Comment: I get the same error even with 4.8.1

Comment: I think you should give it a try with 4.8.1 [Arquillian core is compiled against 4.8.1](http://arquillian.org/modules/core-platform/)

Comment: yes.. I changed.. I get the same error even with 4.8.1...

Comment: could to share zip of your project.

Comment: Sorry.. I can't do that... but maybe you have an working example which I can use? if you do.. can you post as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your maven dependencies only list out JUnit and Arquillian JUnit.  You also need an Arquillian container to work with, in order to execute your tests with.  If you in fact have one on the classpath, please update your question, otherwise please add a dependency on one of the Arquillian containers (e.g. JBoss, Tomcat, etc).