# Could not create EventTestRunnerAdaptor when running Arquillian-test

Tags: maven, jpa, junit, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I want to use Arquillian for unit testing my EJB's. 
When I run the test, I get the following exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor`

This is for a homework assignment in a course about enterprise programming. I do have the solution from the lecturer, but that fails with the same exception. 
I have tried:

- double checking persistence.xml and arquillian.xml for errors
- changing JUnit-version, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134354/arquillian-running-tests-not-working)
- ensuring the arquillian configuration is what we are told to use: 
  "Wildfly Managed" with Working Directory = $MODULE_DIR$. I have tried $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ as well, since that was suggested by IDE (intellij).

**Persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">


    <persistence-unit name="JTA" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="wildfly.jpa.default-unit" value="true"/>
            <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:./target/db"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


    <persistence-unit name="DB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:./target/db"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Arquillian.xml**:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">


    <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">target/downloaded_Wildfly/wildfly</property>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

**Part of test class I am trying to run:**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CategoryEjbTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(Category.class, Quiz.class, SubCategory.class, CategoryEjb.class, ResetEjb.class)
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
    }
```

**Relevant dependencies:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- JEE_container for tests -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want the test to run. Instead, I get the following stacktrace and the test are ignored.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:146)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:89)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:49)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManager.initializeAdaptor(AdaptorManager.java:21)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.initializeAdaptor(AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.java:19)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:109)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:144)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ManagerBuilder.create(ManagerBuilder.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:60)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ExtensionLoader.loadVetoed()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.LoadableExtensionLoader.load(LoadableExtensionLoader.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fireProcessing(ManagerImpl.java:295)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:92)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError ... using some version of libs at compile time, but inconsistent ones at runtime. Solution : sort out what versions you are using at runtime. Nothing to do with persistence configuration at all

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a straight-forward way to see what versions are used at runtime?